# Php Loop logic with repeated values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, logic

I need to figure out a logic that has me confused. 
I have an array that looks like this.

```
array (
    0 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_588'
        'email' => 'abc@hotmail.com'
    ),
    1 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_588'
        'email' => 'def@hotmail.com'
    ),
    2 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_589'
        'email' => 'ninja@hotmail.com'
    ),
    3 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_589'
        'email' => 'ghi@hotmail.com'
    ),
    4 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_590'
        'email' => '123@hotmail.com'
    ),
    5 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_590'
        'email' => '123@hotmail.com'
    ),
    6 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_591'
        'email' => '456@hotmail.com'
    ),
    7 => array (
        'invoice_id' => 'WUI_591'
        'email' => '456@hotmail.com'
    ),
)
```

So if I were to print the array in table layout I would get something like this:-

```
INDEX | INVOICE ID | EMAIL 
  0   |   WUI_588  | abc@hotmail.com
  1   |   WUI_588  | def@hotmail.com
  2   |   WUI_589  | ninja@hotmail.com
  3   |   WUI_589  | ghi@hotmail.com
```

What I want is something like this:-

```
INDEX | INVOICE ID | EMAIL 
  0   |   WUI_588  | abc@hotmail.com, def@hotmail.com
  1   |   WUI_589  | ninja@hotmail.com, ghi@hotmail.com
```

....and so on. 
One of the attempts I made is this,

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $invoiceidbucket[] = $value['invoice_id'];
  if(in_array($value['invoice_id'], $invoiceidbucket)) {
    $value['merged_email'][] = $value['email'];

    //Clearing array
    $invoiceidbucket = array;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code that you tried or the one that you arrived at first one

Comment: @Thamilan, I added an unsuccessful solution.

Comment: Look at @Saty's answer. They bet me before answering yours :)

Comment: @Thamilan are you using the same logic ??

Comment: @Saty, Nope. Somewhat different but using same built in methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a desired array by using below code:-

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($initial_array as $arr){
  $final_array[$arr['invoice_id']]['invoice_id'] = $arr['invoice_id'];
  $final_array[$arr['invoice_id']]['email'] = (!empty($final_array[$arr['invoice_id']]['email']))?$final_array[$arr['invoice_id']]['email'].','.$arr['email'] : $arr['email'];
}
$final_array = array_values($final_array);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/785516

Note:- Now use this `$final_array` in your loop (`foreach()`) and print in desired manner

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$a = [];//Your array;
$retArray = []; //Output Array
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $retArray['invoice_id'][] =  $retArray['email'];
}
```

At the end of the loop, you'll have all the invoice_ids as key with array of their email-ids.

Print anyway you like after this :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a check through the invoice ID column loop before starting a new row. in case of a match found, put the email in the same row, with another check which would add a comma before, in case its not the 1st email ID of the row.

May be show us how you approached it.

Answer (score 0):

My method doesn't do needless iterated overwriting.  I recommend this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aSDhK))

```
$array=[
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_588','email'=>'abc@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_588','email'=>'def@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_589','email'=>'ninja@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_589','email'=>'ghi@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_590','email'=>'123@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_590','email'=>'123@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_591','email'=>'456@hotmail.com'],
    ['invoice_id'=>'WUI_591','email'=>'456@hotmail.com']
];
foreach($array as $row){  // iterate all rows
    if(!isset($result[$row['invoice_id']])){  // if first occurrence of invoice_id...
        $result[$row['invoice_id']]=$row;     // save the full row with invoice_id as the temporary key
    }else{                                    // if not the first occurrence of invoice_id...
        $result[$row['invoice_id']]['email'].=", {$row['email']}";  // concatenate the email value
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'invoice_id' => 'WUI_588',
    'email' => 'abc@hotmail.com, def@hotmail.com',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'invoice_id' => 'WUI_589',
    'email' => 'ninja@hotmail.com, ghi@hotmail.com',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'invoice_id' => 'WUI_590',
    'email' => '123@hotmail.com, 123@hotmail.com',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'invoice_id' => 'WUI_591',
    'email' => '456@hotmail.com, 456@hotmail.com',
  ),
)
```